# What is name of full course

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, youtube

Anyone Know full Course link or Name of Course OR any source name of this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9FlnOPltA8

This is SQL cluster index architecture video. anyone know full course name or Link ?

Please share ..

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a problem related to your code, so this isn't the best forum to post in.

Having said that, the video you linked looks like a once off video related specifically to "Microsoft SQL Server Index Architecture". If you're looking for courses/ tutorials on Microsoft SQL, then here's two free ones I found on Udemy:

[Microsoft SQL Server - An Introduction (2018 edition)](https://www.udemy.com/course/microsoft-sql-server-an-introduction-2018-edition/)

[Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Database Administration](https://www.udemy.com/course/microsoft-sql-server-2014-database-administration/)